# how to pass generic interface in constructor of a class with type of that class with autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following classes and interfaces in c#. I cant figure out how to register them with AutoFac.

```
    public interface ICustomer{void Validate();}
    public interface IValidation<T>{void Validate(T obj);}
    public class CustomerBase : ICustomer
    {
        private IValidation<ICustomer> validation = null;
        public CustomerBase(IValidation<ICustomer> obj)
        {
            validation = obj;
        }
        public virtual void Validate()=>validation.Validate(this);

    }
    public class Lead : CustomerBase
    {
        public Lead(IValidation<ICustomer> obj) : base(obj){}
    }
    public class LeadValidation : IValidation<ICustomer>
    {
        public void Validate(ICustomer obj){//Now validation Here......}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your components for the Dependency Injection. That's done by creating a `ContainerBuilder` and registering your components.

```cs
// create the ContainerBuilder
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// register your components
builder.RegisterType<MyConcreteType1>().As<IMyInterface1>();
builder.RegisterInstance(new MyConcreteType2()).As<IMyInterface2>();
...

// build your container
var myContainer = builder.Build();
```

And then to get your required component all you have to do is

```cs
// create a scope so AutoFac will take care of 
// disposing of objects you no longer need
using (var scope = myContainer.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  // resolve the components you need. AutoFac will take care of
  // resolving their dependencies and instantiating them for you
  var requiredComponent = scope.Resolve<IMyInterface1>();

  // now you can use your components!
}
```

Here's a very useful video that will help you understand how to use AutoFac and its purpose: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCUNrRtVVWY